# how to do a loop in powershell, including powershell Switch?

Tags: powershell, loops, switch-statement

What is the best way, to make a loop in powershell? including powershell Switch,
So that every time you finish, you will return to the Switch to be rerun
example:

$list_of_scripts=Read-Host "welcome to AD tool :)
select: 1: new user
2: new OU
Switch ($list_of_scripts){

1 { $name=Read-Host "enter the user name"
New-ADUser -Name $name -Accountpassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword") -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true
}

2 {$username=Read-Host "Enter OU name"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -name $username -Path "DC=slipknot,DC=main" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False}}

what i tried:

$list_of_scripts = $scripts
foreach ($script in $scripts) {

"welcome to AD tool :)
select: 1: new user
2: new OU"

Switch ($list_of_scripts)

$script=1 {$name=Read-Host "enter the user name"
New-ADUser -Name $name -Accountpassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword") -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true}

$script=2 {$username=Read-Host "Enter OU name"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -name $username -Path "DC=slipknot,DC=main"}}}

Comment: Please format code samples [as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: ***As posted, regardless of the use case, that code is not proper. ***  Use the PS ISE or VSCode snippet tool ```CRTL+J and Shift+CRTL+Spacebar``` to see a snippet sample for you to refactor. Yet, you seem to be asking to build a menu that allows a user to supply data, complete a task and come back to the beginning menu.  You can do this using Out-GridView as a GUI, with proper calls to the code nodes. It would be the same approach in any MenuApp and its code behind language.  I've posted examples in the locations if you can to see them, you can reach me via the stackoverflow chat feature.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to ask the user once at the start of the script run whether they want to add users or OU's, and then after that point loop round adding more of the same (eg re-using the result of the Read-Host line)?

If so then probably the easiest option is to simply use a Do While loop between the Read-Host line and the Switch statement. Eg,

```
$list_of_scripts=Read-Host "welcome to AD tool :) select: 1: new user 2: new OU 

Do {

Switch ($list_of_scripts){

1 { $name=Read-Host "enter the user name" New-ADUser -Name $name -Accountpassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword") -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true }

2 {$username=Read-Host "Enter OU name" New-ADOrganizationalUnit -name $username -Path "DC=slipknot,DC=main" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False}

}

While {$name -ne "" -and $username -ne ""}
```

which will then cause it to loop round prompting to enter the username or OU name as required until you don't enter anything when prompted and just hit return.